# Чи коректно говорити "функціонал сайту"?

Tags: терміни, запозичені-слова

Вираз *функціонал сайту* є досить поширеним, в чому можна переконатись, скориставшись пошукачем Google.

Проте, функціонал є математичним терміном і [означає](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB) *відображення векторного простору на базову множину для даного простору, здебільшого на множину дійсних чисел*.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/) не містить слова *функціонал*.

Чи є *функціонал* унормованим варіантом з точки зору опису характеристик продукту/сайту чи потрібно використовувати виключно вираз *функціональність сайту*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мені здається це той випадок, коли ми рухаємося паралельно російській мові, маючи подібні (чи кальковані?) слова з тими ж значеннями і повторюємо ті ж самі помилки.

Функціональність (як і рос. «функциональность») означає:

1. Множина [функцій](http://sum.in.ua/s/funkcija) (1–3), що їх має певний предмет/прилад система.
2. Іменник до «функціональний» в значенні:

   - Функціональний — той, що здатен виконувати корисні функції або багато функцій; корисний; практичий.

   Тобто, певною мірою гіпонім до [практичність](http://sum.in.ua/s/praktychnistj) (1).

Функціонал (аналогічно до рос. [функционал](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB)) означає:

1. Математичне поняття.
2. Синонім до «функціональність» (1).

<sub>Визначення грубі і мої. Може, спочатку додам в український Wiktionary із цитатами з корпусу в ролі доведення. І тоді вже вточню тут доведеннями.</sub>

В словниках російської мови друге значення другого слова відмічене як *неол[огізм]*, *жарг[он]*. Існує не одна сторінка, де росіян [намагаються привчити не використовувати друге слово в жаргонному другому значенні замість першого слова](http://pavelf.ru/function/).

Я припускаю, що «функціонал» (2) в українській мові теж є неологізмом і жаргоном. Тим не менш воно [широко використовується](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB). Припускаю, що скоро воно може бути визнане нежаргонним. Тим більше, що значення «функціональність» (1) теж є досить новим порівняно з «функціональність» (2), яке ми зустрічаємо, наприклад, у Ю. Щербака (1971) та П. Загребельного (1986).

Answer (score 3):

Слово *functional* - це прикметник, дослівно - функціональний. Стосовно функцій, воно перетворилось на іменник і має на увазі функцію аргументами якої є інші функції. Тоді ж як функціонал сайту - це список наявних функцій. Як бачимо зв'язку немає і значення, яке ми маємо в російській та українських мовах імовірно утворилась завдяки скороченню слова *функціональність* задля зручності використання.

Утворення відприкметникових іменників це нормальний процес. Але тут творення якесь не рідне нашій мові. Як варіант скорочення можу запропонувати **функційність сайту**, такий словотвір є природнім для нашої мови. Таку ідею можна угледіти на [r2u](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=functional&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> **functional capabilities** = функці́йні (функціона́льні) можли́вості

А функціональні можливості сайту це і є набір функцій сайту, на відміну від нефункціональних, до яких зараховуємо зазвичай ті, що описують якість сервісу, такі як надійність, безпека, час відгуку і т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Дуже цікаве запитання! Пропрацювавши більше 10 років в сфері ІТ, ніколи навіть не задумувався, що говорити "функціонал" може бути граматично не вірно. У нас використовується лише це слово і завжди в значенні іменника.

*Мені потрібно до завтра протестувати цей функціонал*

*Який новий функціонал буде містити нова версія нашого продукту?*

Comment: Не "граматично", а "семантично". В українській мові "функціонал" —  звісно, іменник (то про англ. казали, що там functional — в першу чергу, прикметник). А в українській "функціонал" може бути лише іменником. Просто питання в тому, чи дозволено це слово використовувати в якихось інших сенсах, окрім вузького суто математичного.

Comment: І, дякую за відповідь, але це фактично не є повною відповіддю. Бо тут прийнято давати об'єктивно аргументовані відповіді. А «в нас так кажуть» — важливий, але не найоб'єктивніший аргумент. Хоча як коментар це було би корисно.

Comment: А в мене навпаки ситуація: що в універі, що на роботі переважно вживалось функціональність, якщо хтось казав функціонал - поправляли. Мабуть, звязано з тим, що більший нахил на математику був, тому це слово мало міцну асоціацію з тим, що воно насправді означає.